# Nginx Empty GIF Module

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Suppose request hits my web application like this:

```
_http://mywebapp/empty.gif?data1=abc&data2=123
```

By using `Nginx`'s `empty_gif` module, I am doing something like:

```
location /empty.gif {
        expires -1;
        post_action /empty_gif_post;        
        empty_gif;
}

location = /empty_gif_post {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://mywebapp/_track.php;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it won't let me retrieve `GET` parameters.

Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to remove `internal` from your `proxy pass` as gif serves to clients and not within `nginX`.

Now do as below:

```
proxy_pass foo.php$is_args$args
```

Comment: location = /empty_gif_post { 
       internal; proxy_pass http://mywebapp/_track.php$is_args$args; 
}

didn't work

Comment: That would be because you have specified it as internal. An internal location can only be accessed from within Nginx, an empty gif to the client is not internal.